How can I convert a function cell into a string automatically?
I have a file with a concatenate formula, since I will share this file, I don't want people to struggle when they will copy the text (I suppose some of them will try to double click on the formula cell and see it, it is not what I want).
What I am trying to do is to automatically convert the cell formula into a text so it appears as if someone just write a text in a cell without any formula.
How can I do this?
Here is a file example. I tryed to use the TEXT function but it endend the same, unless it is possible to have like: a formula in a column that I hide that will send the result in the right column.

Consider providing input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Click here to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

Your file can't be accessed. But you can use the hidden column with a formula like this:
=HSTACK("Put anything here",YOUR FORMULA)

For example, the formula would be put in A1, and say "Put anything here" in the A1 and the result of the formula in B1:

See what I get in B1:


Thank you so much! it is exactly what I was looking for

I'm glad it was useful! Consider marking the question as answered ;)
